# How do I pass data to a method being run as a MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

What I'm really trying to do is create a Quartz job that doesn't run concurrently, but also can access the `JobExecutionContext` in order to get the `previousFireTime`.  Here's my object:

```
// imports...

public class UtilityObject {

    private SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    public UtilityObject(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
        Date prevDate = ctx.getPreviousFireTime();

        // rest of the code...
    }
}
```

And here's how I've configured my bean:

```
<bean name="utilityBean" class="UtilityObject" />

<bean id="utilityJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetOjbect" ref="utilityBean" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="execute" />
   <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean name="utilityTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="utilityJob" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="5000" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="20000" />
</bean>
```

When I try to run this, it fails during the creation of the bean with

> NoSuchMethodException: UtilityJob.execute()

Any ideas?

**Solution**:

After reading skaffman's answer, I was able to get my solution working.  Using the trigger that I had, I knew that the name was, and figured out that the default group was 'DEFAULT'.  I had my class extend the `QuartzJobBean` class, and then added this bit of code:

```
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) 
               throws JobExecutionException {
    boolean isRunning = 
           (ctx.getScheduler().getTriggerState("utilityTrigger", "DEFAULT") ==
               Trigger.STATE_BLOCKED);

    if (isRunning) {
        // run the job
    }
}
```

Sorry for the weird formatting; these are some long lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` is handy, but primitive - it can only execute public methods with no arguments.

If your job needs access to the Quartz API, then you'll need to use `JobDetailBean` and `QuartzJobBean` instead of `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean`. See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz-jobdetail) for instructions how. The `QuartzJobBean` is passed the current `JobExecutionContext` when it runs.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm modifying my question to include the answer that I eventually came to after reading your answer.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to pass arguments to `MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean` in the same way as with a spring `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` using the arguments property.

For example:

```
<bean id="myJob"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="myBean" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="myMethod" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>greetings</value>
            <ref bean="anotherBean"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```